# Channel Images field messing up display of channel form

Tags: safecracker, channel-images

EE 4.3.8
Channel Images 7.1.0

I have a channel form that contains a Channel Images field. But this field is causing the entire output of the template to be wrapped in a `<pre>` tag pair which messes up the display of the entire page.

```
 <fieldset class="reqborder" style="display:block; float:left; clear:left; width:95%; margin-bottom:15px">
    <legend  ><strong>Photo of Applicant</strong></legend>
                <div class="clearfloat" style="margin-bottom:12px"></div>
    <label for="headshot" style="font-weight:normal"><span class="reqbold">Headshot <span class="req">* Required </span></span>
      Upload -one only- recent photo of yourself. If you have an actor headshot/resume, upload that. Monologue Workshop & On-Camera Audition require a current acting headshot/resume to be uploaded here, and one presented at the interview.</label>
                     <div class="clearfloat" style="margin-bottom:22px"></div>

 <div>  {field:headshot}</div>
            <div class="clearfloat" style="margin-bottom:12px"></div>

           </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is caused by known bug.

Temporary fix:

Edit the `system/user/addons/channel_images/ft.channel_images.php` file and remove the `echo '<pre>';` on or around line 121, that should solve that issue.